# In FullCalendar (v6), which is better, eventContent or eventDidMount?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I would like to display an image that will be an icon to the left of the title that appears on the calendar,
I am not sure whether I should use `eventContent` or `eventDidMount`.
Which do you recommend?

With `eventContent`, I was able to successfully display an image, but as a result, the event with the time set does not display the dot or the time.

With `eventDidMount`, I still can't figure out how to get the image to display, and I can't find out how the el property is configured.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please show what you tried in each case, then we can more easily identify a specific issue. eventContent replaces the entire content of the event's HTML, so if you _only_ included the image and did not replace the rest of it, what you've described sounds quite likely. I'd therefore suggest that eventDidMount with a callback function is probably a better option.